# jQuery how to get keypress() to listen for any pressed key that isn't what you specify

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get letters in a word to change color to red when I type and I want them to do it sequentially.  However, I want it so that if someone types in an incorrect letter in that word, the previous letters will lose their color. Here's how it's set up in the HTML file:

```
<p>Type the <span id="k">k</span><span id="a">a</span><span id="t">t</span> keys on your keyboard to change the letters red.</p>
```

In this example the word is "kat". Each letter changes to red as I type it. However, I want to make it so if I press any key other than "t" after the "ka", then "red" class is removed from "k" and "a".  Is this possible?

```
    $(document).keypress(function(e) {
    switch(e.which) {
        case 107: $("#k").addClass('red');
    }

    if ($("#k").hasClass("red")) {
        switch(e.which) {
            case 97: $("#a").addClass('red');
        }
    }

    if ($("#a").hasClass("red")) {
        switch(e.which) {
            case 116: $("#t").addClass('red');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: kat is spelled **c** **a** **t**

Comment: are you just trying to see if the next letters pressed match some defined word until it's a complete match?

Comment: I love riddles like this one :) I'm on it ...

Comment: hunter, i saw an answer from you, but i don't know where it went? seems to have disappeared but it did work like what i was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Live demo:*** http://jsfiddle.net/fZrwE/3/

HTML:

```
<span id="word">
    <span>H</span>
    <span>e</span>
    <span>l</span>
    <span>l</span>
    <span>o</span>
</span>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    var p = 'pressed',
        s = $('#word > span'),
        l = s.not('.' + p).first(),
        c = l.text().charCodeAt(0);

    e.which == c ? l.addClass(p) : s.removeClass(p);
});
```

Explanation:

The keypress handler has 4 local variables:
`p` is the class name for a pressed letter,
`s` is a jQuery collection of letters (SPAN elements inside the `#word` element),
`l` is the first SPAN from `s` that doesn't have the `p` class, ergo, that has not yet been pressed - note that this is the letter that has to be pressed next,
`c` is the code for that letter.

If `e.which` (the code for the letter that has been pressed by the user) is the same as `c`, then that means that the user pressed the correct letter, and this letter - which is referenced via `l` - will receive the `p` class. Otherwise, just reset the whole word, ergo, remove the `p` class from all the letters.

Comment: @jnguyen I've added an explanation. If you have further questions, be specific.

Comment: thanks for writing out an explanation.  however, i tested the code and it doesn't seem to be working. shouldn't the letters "h" "e" "l" "l" "o" be changing to red as i type each of them? i tried it in the jsfiddle link you gave and they don't turn red. do they turn red for you?

Comment: Oh my mistake! I didn't realize I was supposed to be typing 'H' instead 'h' (uppercase vs. lowercase). your code worked marvelously. thanks a lot for your help.